# Kubernetes create secret from json

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I have this json

```
{'kind': 'Secret', 'foo': 'secret_value'}
```

How can I use this json to create a secret in Kubernetes?

I want to run the equivalent of

```
kubectl create secret {'kind': 'Secret', 'foo': 'secret_value'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kubectl create secret generic secret-name --from-file=./your-file.json`

or

`kubectl create secret generic secret-name --from-literal=foo=secret_value`